# Which focus points on the Nikon D750 support f/8?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, nikon-d750

The Nikon D750 [has](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d750/spec.htm) 11 autofocus points rated up to f/8. Which ones are the f/8 points?

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, Nikon has historically been very closed-lipped about the exact specifications of their AF systems. Unlike Canon, who publish comprehensive guides about theirs, Nikon seems to treat that information like state secrets. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelClark. I'm going to contact Nikon with this question and will post here if they respond.

Comment: I guess that those will be the save as ones for D4S - more [**here**](http://nps.nikonimaging.com/technical_solutions/d4s_tips/basic_settings/index.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Nikon D750 User’s Manual (rev. 03), there are 11 to 15 autofocus points rated up to f/8. On page 430, the manual details which points work with different lens and teleconverter combinations.

The 15 points that usually work at f/8 comprise the 3×3 square around the center point, a row of 3 points to the right of the square’s middle right point and a row of 3 points to the left of the square’s middle left point.

The 11 points that always work at f/8 are the center point, a row of 4 points to the right of the center point and a row of 4 points to the left of the center point, the point directly above the center point and the point directly below the center point.

[image: Nikon D750 User’s Manual rev. 03, page 430]

The TC-14E series of teleconverters lose about 1 stop of light, the TC-17E II loses about 1.5 stops, and the TC-20E series lose about 2 stops.